# Is gravitation time dilation simply c/v?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, time, inertial-frames

Recently, I've been very interested in forms of time dilation. I'm relatively new to relativity, so I apologize for any stupid mistake I may make.

I was messing with the equation for gravitational time dilation when I came across an odd result. As far as I know,
$ t' = t \ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{gr}{c^2}}} $

Since this radius is effectively height,
$$
t' = t \ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{gh}{c^2}}} = t \ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{mgh}{mc^2}}}
$$
$$
t' = t \ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{PE}{E}}}
$$

Assuming that the only present forms of energy are Newtonian potential and kinetic (since I can't think of any others), $E = KE + PE $, so
$$
t' = t \ \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{PE + KE}{E} - \frac{PE}{E}}} = t \ \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{KE}{E}}} = t \ \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\frac{mv^2}{mc^2}}} = \frac{ct\sqrt{2}}{v}
$$

Which doesn't make very much sense, since acceleration isn't a factor. Clearly, I did something wrong. Are they more forms of energy in this situation than kinetic and potential, or is it possible that I am just using equations that are invalid in this scenario? I've considered that I might be using rest-mass as opposed to relative mass, or vise-versa. If anyone knows what I did wrong, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that $E=mc^2$ is false here. That's only rest energy: the complete formula would be $E=mc^2 + \frac12 mv^2 + mgh$ (in the non relativistic limit).